# Hosted the website in godaddy. How to create wordpress web-site?

Tags: wordpress

We have a domain hosted in godaddy. The web-site works fine without any issues.

Now we would like to use wordpress and wordpress themes and plugin to build the web-site

How do install or deploy wordpress in godaddy?

Thanks.

Comment: There are guides on Godaddy on how to do this. Stackoverflow isn't the place to be asking how to use simple Godaddy services.. https://uk.godaddy.com/help/install-wordpress-on-a-web-or-classic-hosting-account-834

Answer (score 0):

In godaddy, there is an option for one click install wordpress.

Or

If you want to install wordpress manually follow the below steps :

- Download and unzip the WordPress package if you haven't already.
- Create a database for WordPress on your web server, as well as a MySQL (or MariaDB) user who has all privileges for accessing and modifying it.
- (Optional) Find and rename `wp-config-sample.php` to `wp-config.php`, then edit the file (see Editing wp-config.php) and add your database information.
- Upload the WordPress files to the desired location on your web server:
- Run the WordPress installation script by accessing the URL in a web browser. This should be the URL where you uploaded the WordPress files.

  For more details see this link [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)

Comment: 1, Upload the WordPress files to the desired location on your web server: what is the actual location where we need to place it ?

Comment: 2. Run the WordPress installation script by accessing the URL in a web browser. what is the script name to be executed in the browser? any sample URL

Comment: on your root directory, most of the server have public_html

Comment: simple only your registered domain name example http://example.com , if you want to create inside your sub folder then create folder inside public_html/demo and then access http://example.com/demo

Comment: If it help you then mark as answer so other developer also help this. Thanks :)

Comment: We should have index.php or index.html so that the user enters the domain it should navigate and opens the first file. Which file will be the first index.php or index.html or any file ??? where this configuration exist to reroute to a different file